# Regex expression in R to detect single digit and two digits keeping the delimiters

Tags: r, regex, delimiter, tidyr

I am trying to split row into multiple rows using the tidy R package.

This is a single cell in my dataset

```
column 1
 1. a
 2. b
33. c

df = separate_rows(df,`column 1`, sep = "(?=\\d[\\.]\\s)"
```

When I use the above code:

I get

```
Actual Output  |  Desired Output
1. a           |      1. a
2. b           |      2. b  
3              |     33. c
3. c           |
```

Comment: Please provide some reproducible data.

Comment: Do you mean this? `df %>% separate(column_1, into = c('v1', 'v2'), sep = '. ')`

Comment: Or, try fixing your approach with ``separate_rows(df,`column 1`, sep = "(?m)(?!\\A)(?=^\\d+\\.\\s)")`` if you are just splitting multiline text.

Comment: No,  I am trying to split a single row into multiple rows. When I use this regex "(?=\\d[\\.]\\s)" , it is able to detect single digit numbers with the period symbol but when it comes to detecting two digits and a period it is splitting it into two separate rows.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - Can you share any documents which will help me understand regex expressions better?

Comment: You may read through [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info), [regex SO tag description](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) (with many other links to great online resources), and the community SO post called [What does the regex mean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean). Also, [rexegg.com](http://rexegg.com) is worth having a look at. Basic regex lessons are available at [regexone.com](http://regexone.com/).

Comment: What if i have to detect a pattern with a number followed by a bracket? What would be the regex for this?  
`1) 2) 3)
to be split into three rows
1
2
3
I tried separate_rows(df,`column 1`, sep = "(?m)(?!\\A)(?=^\\d+\\D\\s)")
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
separate_rows(df,`column 1`, sep = "(?m)(?!\\A)(?=^\\d+\\.\\s)")
```

**Regex details**

- `(?m)` - `^` now matches start of a line position
- `(?!\A)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match when at the start of  a string
- `(?=^\d+\.\s)` - a positive lookahead that, immediately to the right of the current location, requires

  - `^` - start of a line
  - `\d+` - 1+ digits
  - `\.` - a dot
  - `\s` - a whitespace.